# NextJS project not generating static pages on build. Fails with timeout error

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am working on NextJS project with TypeScript. For some strange reasons it is failing to compile either for development or production. It fails with timeout error as shown in the following error trace

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Static page generation for /posts/introducing-hapana-v1 is still timing out after 3 attempts. See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-page-generation-timeout
    at onRestart (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:487:31)
    at Worker.exportPage (/app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/worker.js:49:40)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:412:32
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:407:9
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:987:17
```

This following is the dynamic page `[slug].tsx`

```
const PostDetailsPage: React.FC<PostDetailsProps> = (props) => {
  // console.log(post);

  const { post, posts } = props;

  if (!post || !posts) return <Loader />;

  return <Post post={post} posts={posts} />;
};

export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
  const slug = context.params.slug;

  const { data: postData } = await getPost(slug);
  const { data: posts }: DataInterface = await getBlogPosts(1);
  return {
    props: {
      post: postData,
      posts: posts.results,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data: posts }: DataInterface = await getBlogPosts(1);
  const slugs = posts.results.map((p) => ({ params: { slug: p.slug } }));
  return {
    paths: slugs,
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export default PostDetailsPage;
```

```
export const getBlogPosts = (page: number) => {
  return http.get(apiEndpoint + `posts/?cats=blog&page=${page}`);
};
```

```
export const getPost = (postSlug: string) => {
  return http.get(postUrl("posts/" + postSlug + "/"));
};
```

Please note `http` is just an axios interceptor function
Could anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: could you share with us the getBlogPosts() and getPost functions, thanks

Comment: Hello. I did update the question with those functions

Comment: Are you able to successfully call those same API endpoints from Postman? Do they not time out or take a long time to resolve there?

Comment: Try put the http requests in the functions like getStaticProps, maybe you're running into async problem as well. I'm not sure

Comment: I just found what the issue was. There was buggy functional child component  for ```Post``` . I believe NextJS should give a better error than the current one. I think I am gonna delete the question or what do you think guys?

Comment: @Muteshi How did you debug the functional child component ? Can you please share the full description in the answer , how it got resolved ?